# Jupyterhub: how to allow user manage their python packages

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Just wondering if there is a way to allow individual user to install the packages/libraries for their notebooks instead of asking system admin to do that for them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **python virtual environments** for this: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/. Virtual environments allow users to create sandboxed environments to do development or testing with. Best of all, each user wouldn't have to worry about messing up their system level python configurations and can blow away any created virtual environment if necessary for a fresh start. Each user **wouldn't need system admin rights** since each virtual environment can exist in *'user land'* and each user can just proxy with pip to install whatever library they needed if they're behind a corporate firewall. For example, to work in a virtual environment and install any necessary software to run a python program (Jupyter notebooks in your case):

```
    # create virtual environment
    $ virtualenv ENV

    # activate virtual environment i.e. work in said environment
    source bin/activate

    #install necessary python library/libraries (can even use a requirements file)
    pip install <lib> --proxy <proxy>
```

where <lib> is the library they're trying to install and <proxy> is your company's proxy if you're behind a corporate firewall. I would also look into virtualenvwrapper to utilize convenience methods for working with python virtual environments: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you Nathan, would the installed packages be available in each worker node? we are on Cloudera cluster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't worked with Cloudera clusters before so I can't say for certain.. But it would depend on whether or not each worker node was sharing the same storage area, if so I suspect you could share virtual environments. If not, you would have to create a script to be ran for each newly created worker node that would install the necessary dependencies. If that's the case I would create a requirement.txt file that each worker node could use to pip install necessary dependencies after creating a virtual environment.